# Processing data on disk with a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, hdf5, pytables

Is there a way to take a very large amount of data on disk (a few 100 GB) and interact with it on disk as a pandas dataframe?

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Described the data using pytables and this example: 
   http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/introduction.html
2. Run a test by loading a portion of the data (a few GB) into an HDF5 file
3. Converted the data into a dataframe using pd.DataFrame.from_records()

This last step loads all the data in memory.

I've looked for some way to describe the data as a pandas dataframe in step 1 but haven't been able to find a good set of instructions to do that.  Is what I want to do feasible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'interact with it'? What would you like to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

[blaze](http://blaze.pydata.org/en/latest/) is a nice way to interact with out-of-core data by using lazy expression evaluation. This uses `pandas` and `PyTables` under the hood (as well as a host of conversions with [odo](http://odo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/))

Comment: Jeff,  I'll take a look.

Comment: There was a nice demo of it at [SEA](https://sea.ucar.edu/event/out-core-computations-blaze).

Comment: Here is a related talk about ``dask`` (mrocklin is one of the authors of blaze), see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLME2WKTJJ8)